# GPS Navigation in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I am developing an iPhone application. I have used mapkit to show the locations for user to select as source and destination. User also have option to see routes between source and destination. I need to implement the turn by turn navigation. I am using google maps.
Is there any other way or any 3rd party library, by which I can implement turn by turn navigation?

Comment: I don't want to use google's navigation. I want to implement the custom navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Please google around before asking questions. There are tons of good tutorials (both free and paid on how to use mapkit.

This is one of them : http://www.ioscreator.com/search?q=mapkit

for turn by turn using maps I have this code snippet layout around here for Apple Maps :

```
let address = "\(self.street!) \(self.zip!) \(self.city!) \(self.country!)"
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler:
    {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) in
        if error != nil {
            let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Cannot locate address", message: "Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            errorAlert.show()
        }

        if placemarks.count > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
            let location = placemark.location

            println("\(location.coordinate.latitude) \(location.coordinate.longitude)")

            let coords = location.coordinate

            let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coords, addressDictionary: nil)
            let mapItem = MKMapItem (placemark: place)

            mapItem.name = locationName

            let options = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey: true]
            MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([mapItem], launchOptions: options as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Google maps is pretty similar, and again very easy to find a well written tutorial online, this was my first hit using :

> swift navigate google maps

as search keywords in google

http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/

PS I didn't downvote, but I understand why that person did it.

Comment: But I don't want google App for navigation. I want to implement my own custom navigation.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  He doesnt want to open the maps app to navigate.  He wants to code the navigation part himself.